# KIF (Keep It Functional) distinguish between iPhone and iPad

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ipad, kif

I am using KIF for testing the functionality of an app. However, this app has two versions, one is for iPad, and the other one is for iPhone. Is there a global variable or something that indicates if I am running my test in iPad or iPhone? I'd like to use it (e.g. in a conditional) to take advantage and just make a few modifications in the iPhone tests that I have already finished.

Comment: I think KIF is irrelevant here - you can test the same way you normally would.

Comment: Yes, it is. I noticed it a few minutes ago. The reason is I am new using xcode. Thank you Aaron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define macro

```
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() != UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
```

That's how we used it.

Comment: You might want to future-proof with `== UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad`. `UIUserInterfaceIdiomWatch` and `UIUserInterfaceIdiomCar` could be just around the corner…

Comment: Undocumented UIUserInterfaceIdiomWatch with value of 4 works.